# Why does didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation in a category cause issues with UISplitView?

Tags: ios, rotation, uisplitviewcontroller, objective-c-category, screen-rotation

I have a tabbed app with a a UISplitView in one of the tabs.

I'm using [UITabBarController+iAds](https://github.com/jvashishtha/UITabBarController-iAds) and have an issue which the dev has so far not been able to solve.

Unfortunately, this is what my UI looks like on rotation of the iPad:

[image]
[image]

The category is called from within AppDelegate and the following code is used to refresh the ad when the device is rotated:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    NSLog(@"Did rotate");
    [self layoutBanner];
}
```

As I understand it, this is preventing the MasterViewController from working correctly but I don't fully understand the principle behind the cascading of method calls to understand how to fix this issue.

Comment: What happens if you do not call `[self layoutBanner]`
?

Comment: The issues still appear but the ad banner is not reloaded.

Answer (score 7):

Here's what the Apple Developer Guide says about the [didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:) method:

> Subclasses may override this method to perform additional actions
>   immediately after the rotation.
>
> **...**
>
> **Your implementation of this method must call super at some point
>   during its execution.**

My best guess is that certain drawing operations in the view controller doesn't happen because you're not calling the superclass method from your implementation. Try to fix it like this:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    [super didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:fromInterfaceOrientation];
    NSLog(@"Did rotate");
    [self layoutBanner];
}
```

**UPDATE:** 
On iOS 8 this method is deprecated and no longer called when the device is rotated. Instead you need to use a new method:

```
- (void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];
    NSLog(@"Szie changed");
    [self layoutBanner];
}
```

Comment: I'm sure I tried this and it didn't work. However, I can't retry this since iOS 8 because for some reason didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation is not being called on iOS 8 devices. It seems to be an issue within Categories rather than ViewControllers.

Comment: The reaason is that Apple made it deprecated in iOS 8. I updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Okay this worked and it doesn't suffer from the problem in the screenshots. Now I just need to fix the rest of the code. Thanks!